# Homotopy equivalence between pointed CW-complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

Let $f : (X, x_0) \to (Y, y_0)$ a morphism in the category of pointed, connected CW-complexes. Let $A= [1/2, 1]^{+} \wedge X \cup Y \subset C_f$, where $C_f$ is the mapping cone and $X, Y$ are pointed, connected CW-complexes.

I was trying to prove that $A$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y$: I am pretty sure it is the inclusion of $Y$ in $A$ that determines the equivalence, but I have trouble finding an explicit expression of it.

Any hints?

Comment: What is the relation between $X$ and $Y$? Is $X$ is a subcomplex of $Y$?

Comment: Apparently you have a diagram like this: 

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
X &\to & X\land I\\
\downarrow && \downarrow \\ 
Y &\to & (X\land I)\cup Y
\end{array}
$$ and you want to show that the lower horizontal map is an homotopy equivalence, correct? So who is the left vertical map?

Comment: I know that $f :( X, x_0)  \to (Y, y_0)$ and that $A$ is contained in the mapping cone $C_f$.

Comment: @PaulFrost $f$ is not necessarily an inclusion in my hypotheses, it is just a morphism in the category of pointed CW-complexes

Comment: Then you should add this to your question. As it stands, one does not see anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ is a copy of the reduced mapping cylinder of $f$ of which $Y$ is a strong deformation retract.

Comment: Sorry if it is a trivial question: why is $A$ a copy of the reduced mapping cylinder if it is not a quotient?

Comment: The mapping cone is obtained from $[0,1]^+ \wedge X + Y$ by identifying $(x,1)$ with $f(x)$ (this is the mapping cylinder of $f$) and then collapsing $X \times 0$ to a point. The part $B = ([0,1/2]^+ \wedge X)/ (X \times 0)$ is a copy of the cone on $X$. If you remove the interior of this part, you get $A$ which a copy of the reduced mapping cylinder

Comment: So is it implicit that $f(x) \sim (x,1)$ in $A$?

Comment: @cip Yes. If one only sees $A= [1/2, 1]^{+} \wedge X \cup Y$, it is not clear what $A$ is (look at my first comment to your question). But you clarified that $A \subset C_f$, so indeed $f(x) \sim (1,x)$.